# CiviContibute View Customization

Tags: civicontribute

I am using CiviCRM on Joomla. I wanted to know if there is a way to customize how I view the contributions on the admin side (in the back-end). I honestly have no need to see time of donation or premiums (we don't use any right now). Are there any ways to hide these fields to clean up the view?

Comment: Do you mean the front-end form the end-user sees or the back-end admin screen(s)?

Comment: I mean from the back-end, sorry

Comment: Roger that, I've edited the question to clarify.

Comment: Thank you! I thought admin side was clear enough. Looking back though I see why there was confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're asking for isn't possible without coding, unfortunately.  It's a major focus of CiviCRM 5.0 to be able to have user-definable forms in this way.

If you're a coder, or you can hire/borrow one, you can use [hook_civicrm_searchColumns](https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/hook_civicrm_searchColumns) to change which fields show on the Contributions tab.  There's an example in [this blog post](https://civicrm.org/blogs/lobo/introducing-hookcivicrmsearchcolumns-modify-search-results-meet-your-needs).  Finally, I just uploaded an extension I wrote to Github, which replaces the Premium column on the contributions tab with info on soft credits: https://github.com/PalanteJon/coop.palantetech.showsoftcreditsinsummary

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about setting up contribution pages for end-users of your website, you can do quite a bit to customize your contribution pages, both in initial setup and in the profiles used in conjunction with them.  A good place to start is [Set-up | Contributions](http://book.civicrm.org/user/contributions/setup/) and [Profiles here, profiles there, profiles everywhere!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=humFl5X0yCo) (video of CiviCon Denver session)